# Merge old swap file with current file in Vim

Tags: vim

- We have `*.swp` in our `.gitignore` to prevent Vim swap files from getting added to the repository.
- I recently did a `git pull` operation, which pulled the latest updates to a file.
- I had an old Vim swap file that had some changes that I want to preserve.

**Question**: How do I diff / merge the Vim swap file with the current version of the file?

Comment: Have you tried using `vimdiff`?

Comment: @EliSadoff Actually, I haven't tried that. Is that the recommended tool for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can recover the swap file and then do pull again and merge the recovered file with the new version from your remote.